# Unable to load Asset Image in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, image

I have been trying to create a Flutter Application for Web. I have added some asset images bu the images are not loading.
I am not getting any errors or anything but images are not showing.

Below is the code snippet that I'm using.

```dart
const Text(
'You have pushed the button this many times:',
),
Text(
  '$_counter',
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
),
Text("Image should be shown here"),
Image.asset(
  "assets/images/logo.png",
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

pubspec.yaml file

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Below is the screenshot of the home screen:
[image]

Comment: Did you try it with local debug run or deployed to a web server?

Comment: @PeterKoltai I am running this in debug mode

Comment: And you don't get any errors in console? If these are within a `Column`, you can try to wrap the asset image into an `Expanded` widget.

Comment: @PeterKoltai No, I'm not getting any errors also `Expanded` will not be required as I have provided the `height` and `width` of the image.